# Fedora 20 VMware Setup "C Headers" Error?

Tags: fedora, vmware

On Fedora 20, VMware installed without any issues however upon running I was greeted with a prompt asking me to give the path for Kernal Headers      (Version: 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64). I gave the path `/usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64/include` however I was given an error

> "C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions".

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install the `kernel-devel` package also.
So `yum install kernel-devel` .
I tried on Fedora 22, maybe on Fedora 20 the command is

```
yum install kernel-devel-`uname -r`
```

You can search for the right package with `yum search kernel-devel`.

Comment: I have installed kernel-devel (kernel-devel-3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64) I am still getting the error however :/

Comment: for me, after installing (on Fedora 22) kernel-devel-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64, the vmware tools found the kernel-headers folder as /lib/modules/4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64/build/include